# How do you make databindings work in Controls which are in an AdornerLayer?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, adornerlayer

I'm working on a project where i'm rendering controls which are added to an AdornerLayer - However it appears that databindings are non functional.

Are there additional things one has to consider when adding controls to adorners?

For some reason DataTriggers don't have any effect either, as if there is something i am supposed to call, to wire it up properly.

Answer (score 0):

If Databindings are not working for an adorner make sure to call these methods to properly link the Controls

```
AddVisualChild(DisplayedElement);
AddLogicalChild(DisplayedElement);
```